# how to access list within a list of strings in Python

Tags: python, json, list, numpy

I have a list present in Json format having different languages and I want to identify them with their tags before further saving that specific languages into a different list.

Suppose I have a tag of .net and web along with their basic languages and tools used in json format i.e.

```
>>> json_words = """
...     [
...      {".Net": [
...       ["ASP .NET", 3],
...       ["Angular JS", 1]
...      ]},
...      {"Web": [
...       ["Database", 3],
...       ["jQuery", 3]
...      ] }
...     ]
... """
```

Note the closing of square brackets as well. In this example first string in list (in my case .net and web) is considered as tag and the rest are its languages.

Now, I did something like this to check what is returning:

```
>>> import json

>>> important_words = json.loads(json_words)
>>> important_words = [str(s) for s in important_words]
>>> important_words = [item.lower() for item in important_words]

>>> print important_words[0]
[u'[.net]', [u'asp .net', 3], [u'angular js', 1]]
```

But I cannot access tags alone..

```
>>> print important_words[0][1]
u
```

How to access just tags and then its further list. I also tried to make it a numpy array but it didn't help at all.

```
values = np.array(important_words)
```

Its actually the square brackets of list which are bothering me the most... Did I make this json list correctly?

Any kind of help will be appreciated...

Comment: Are you sure this is the code you're running? As it's written it will fail when you try to create `important_words`. You are calling `lower()` on a list (which doesn't have a `lower` mwthod).

Comment: Oh no, this is not the real code... I just gave example that this is what I have in mind... The real code is quite huge so I cannot post it all.

Comment: @Falcon you need to create a small example. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @PeterWood this is a small example... What's the issue in this example?

Comment: @Falcon see my previous link.

Comment: @PeterWood I edited my code now you can run it and it will give you exact same error which I have been facing with. Kindly check now...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do, I'd convert it to a dictionary (orderedDict if you want to keep the order). You can also filter the numbers out of the lists to leave you the list of languages.

```
>>> frameworks = {framework[0]: [language[0] for language in framework[1:]] for framework in _list}
>>> frameworks.keys()
['[.Net]', '[Web]']
>>> frameworks['[.Net]']
['ASP .NET', 'MVC Framework', 'Angular JS', 'AJAX']
>>> frameworks['[Web]']
['Database', 'jQuery', 'Javascript', 'SQL Server', 'Bootstrap', 'Html', 'CSS']
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this will not work as this is just a sample example real _list have more tags in them and in your second output i.e. frameworks ['[.Net]'] you're actually hacking the code which is not correct plus I just want to access languages present in list not the numbers and lastly did you ran this code? its not working for me.

Comment: I did run the code. What python version are you using? What error is it giving?

Comment: I used the `[.Net]' directly as an example. If you don't want the numbers you can remove them as well. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Are you sure your code is working fine? coz when I run your snippet its not working correctly. Rather its giving me output something like this:                            {'[': ['u', "'", 'w', 'e', 'b', "'", ',', ' ', '[', 'u', "'", '.', 'n', 'e', 't', ' ', 'f', 'r', 'a', 'm', 'e', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'k', "'", ',', ' ', '3', ']', ',', ' ', '[', 'u', "'", '.', 'n', 'e', 't', ' ', '2', '.', '0', "'", ',', ' ', '3', '], ']']}

Comment: Are you sure your `_list` is exactly as written in your question?

Answer (score 0):

You are converting a whole `list` into a string:

```
>>> [str(s) for s in important_words]
```

`important_words` is a `list` of lists, e.g. the first `s` will be:

```
>>> important_words[0]
[u'[.Net]', [u'ASP .NET', 3], [u'Angular JS', 1]]
```

When you call `str(s)` you get a string representation of the whole list:

```
>>> str(important_words[0])
u"[u'[.Net]', [u'ASP .NET', 3], [u'Angular JS', 1]]"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you split your list on basis of ':' then you can access your json_words.

```
  >>> json_words = [str(s) for s in json_words]
  >>> json_words = [item.lower() for item in json_words]
  >>> tag_list = {}
  >>> for i in range(0, len(json_words)):
  ...     tag_list[i] = (json_words)[i].split(':')[0] #This will gives you list of first strings
  >>> print tag_list
  {0: "{'.net'", 1: "{'web'"}
  >>> print tag_list.values()
   ["{'.net'", "{'web'"]
```

and for accessing further list split it on basis of comma like this:

```
   >>> dotnet_list = (json_words)[i].split(':')[1].split(',') 
     ["'asp .net'", "'angular js'"]
```

It's a longer approach but a simpler one (I think)